# Disable weak ssl ciphers while using javax.net.ssl.SSLContext

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

I implement secure connetion using javax.net.ssl.SSLContext class, with code:

```
        ...
        SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslcontext.init(null, trustManager, null);
        SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslcontext);
        ...
```

I whould like to disable weak ssl ciphers. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [JavaDoc for SSLSocketFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#getSupportedCipherSuites%28%29)? I paraphrase

> ...Normally, only a subset of these will actually be enabled by default, since this list may include cipher suites which do not meet quality of service requirements...

In other words, you probably shouldn't worry, but if you do, you can explicitly supply your own implementation/extension of the default impl of `SSLSocketFactory` and override said method, or simply set the cipher suites you want enabled on your `SSLSocket`.

Cheers,

Comment: Extending `SSLSocketFactory` is not necessary to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

They are already disabled. If you want to disable more cipher suites, use `SSLSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites()`.

Comment: @downvowtr Please explain what on earth you think is wrong with this answer.

Comment: the question asks how to disable cipher suites on the SSLContext object, your answer shows how to do it on the SSLSocket object. In cases where you're just dealing with the SSLContext, like using HttpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(), I don't see how using the SSLSocket API helps. Just my thoughts, I didn't actually down vote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [3rd party SSLContext builder](https://github.com/soulwing/ssl-context-tools) which allows you to specify white and black lists for ciphers.